# RedShift: insert some distinct columns from all to table

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to insert some distinct columns from all. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (
            contributor_user_id,
            device_id_source,
            device_os,
            device_model,
            device_design,
            device_serial,
            device_carrier,
            device_os_version,
            device_manufacturer,
            device_current_app_build,
            device_current_app_version,
            date_created,
            date_updated,
            edw_date_created)

SELECT DISTINCT ON (pin_connect_id,
            files_device_id_source,
            files_device_os,
            files_device_model,
            files_device_design,
            files_device_serial,
            files_device_carrier,
            files_device_os_version,
            files_device_manufacturer,
            files_device_current_app_build,
            files_device_current_app_version),
            date_created,
            date_updated,
            getdate()
```

But DISTINCT ON doesn't work in RedShift. How I can do it more correctly for RedShift?

Thnx!

Comment: `But DISTINCT ON doesn't work in RedShift` ... your current query won't work as intended in Postgres either, as there is no `ORDER BY` clause.  Please add one.

Comment: RedShift has some different syntax